# How to extract data into an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML code with the following structure:

```
<div class="betting-table">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-col">
            <div class="header-title">SOME TITLE</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="name">
            <div class="name top">SOME NAME</div>
           <div class="name bottom">SOME NAME</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="name">
            <div class="name top">SOME NAME</div>
           <div class="name bottom">SOME NAME</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="betting-table">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-col">
            <div class="header-title">SOME TITLE</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="name">
            <div class="name top">SOME NAME</div>
           <div class="name bottom">SOME NAME</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="name">
            <div class="name top">SOME NAME</div>
           <div class="name bottom">SOME NAME</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need to get is an object of this format:

```
{
  title : header-title,
  name : name-top
}
```

I am currently able to get the names using:

```
function getMatches(){
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('name');
    var arr = Array.from(divs).map(m => {
      let name = m.querySelector('.name.top').innerText;
      return {name : name}
    });
    console.log(arr);
}
```

However what I can't figure out is how to map the Titles for each item, so the first two items would have the first title and the 3rd and 4th item would have the second title.

What is the best possible way to get the data in the data model I have described?

Comment: Is there anything else you did or just the `.getElementsByClassName()` call? The [documentation on that method on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) has examples on how to use its return value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide us with the rest of your code.

Comment: hey, i have edited the answer and provided my code @EternalHour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over all items and then use `parentElement` to access the `header`

```js
const array = [...document.getElementsByClassName('item')].map(i => {
  const title = i.parentElement.querySelector('.header-title').innerHTML;
  const name = i.querySelector('.name.top').innerHTML;
  return {title, name};
});

console.log(array);
```

```html
<div class="betting-table">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-col">
            <div class="header-title">SOME TITLE 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="name">
            <div class="name top">SOME NAME 1</div>
           <div class="name bottom">SOME NAME 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="name">
            <div class="name top">SOME NAME 2</div>
           <div class="name bottom">SOME NAME 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="betting-table">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-col">
            <div class="header-title">SOME TITLE 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="name">
            <div class="name top">SOME NAME 3</div>
           <div class="name bottom">SOME NAME 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="name">
            <div class="name top">SOME NAME 4</div>
           <div class="name bottom">SOME NAME 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working fine, except Im getting this error on name: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null @Kirill Simonov

Comment: @TomášNosek maybe the reason is that in your example you don't have closing quotes around `<div class="name top>`. I have fixed this in my snippet so it has no errors

Comment: @TomášNosek you might also have had this issue before I updated my answer. Initially I thought you have different html structure. Try it now

Answer (score 0):

If you grab the betting table elements and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over them, and for each item within the table `map` over those two, you can produce an array where the first four items and the last two items share the same titles.

```js
// Grab the tables
const tables = document.querySelectorAll('.betting-table');

// `map` over the tables
const arr = [...tables].map(table => {

  // Grab the title
  const title = table.querySelector('.header-title').textContent;

  // Grab each item in the table
  const items = table.querySelectorAll('.item');

  // `map` over the items
  return [...items].map(item => {

    // Grab the name
    const name = item.querySelector('.name.top').textContent;

    // Return an object with the name of the table, and the item name
    return { title, name };
  });

// Finally, flatten the arrays down
}).flat();

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.betting-table {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="betting-table"><div class="header"><div class="header-col"><div class="header-title">one</div></div><div class="item"><div class="name"><div class="name top">two</div><div class="name bottom">three</div></div></div><div class="item"><div class="name"><div class="name top">four</div><div class="name bottom">five</div></div></div></div><div class="betting-table"><div class="header"><div class="header-col"><div class="header-title">six</div></div><div class="item"><div class="name"><div class="name top">seven</div><div class="name bottom">eight</div></div></div><div class="item"><div class="name"><div class="name top">nine</div><div class="name bottom">ten</div></div></div></div>
```